# Calculate values pf CDF in Python efficiently

Tags: python, cdf

I'd like to find the CDF values for points in an series. The points in the series can be thought of as a distribution between -10 and 10.

My first attempt was to rank the values of the series, and then use the ranks to get the CDF values. For instance;

```py
rankedSeries = mySeries.rank()
CDF = rankedSeries/len(mySeries)
```

But is there a faster way with any built in functions? I'll be doing this lots of times with large amounts of data so speed is important

Answer (score 0):

By means of [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), generate histogram of the array. [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) calculates the CDF of the generated histogram. For large arrays, its more efficient than sorting, in terms of processing time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (np.random.rand(100)*20) - 10
bins = 20
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram (data, bins = bins)
cdf = np.cumsum(hist)
plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], cdf/cdf[-1])
plt.show()
```

[image: CDF Plot]

Comment: Would this be any faster though? It doesn't seem like it but honestly I don't have much compsci/software background so I don't know..

Comment: It should be faster since binning will be a O(n) operation, while sorting will at least be O(n log n). However, the difference between the two approaches will be that a cdf value will not be available at each unique data point when using the histogram approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the Empirical Distribution Function (EDF) instead of the CDF for use in Kolmogorov Smirnov, Anderson Darling, or other goodness of fit tests, the following code may help:

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = (np.random.rand(100)*20-10) ++(np.random.rand(100)*20-10)   +  (np.random.rand(100)*20-10)
data.sort()
plt.plot(data,np.arange(len(data)))
plt.show()```
````